# can't clone or add in git repo

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-add

[image]

when ever I'm trying to check my git status or want to clone in my repsitry the cmd is showing me this, can someone report a problem & help me out with an error?

Comment: if you are looking to get changes from remote then use git pull command. git clone is used to make a copy of repository and git pull is used to fetch content from remote repository

Comment: What you're showing is valid output for a `git status`command (there is no error being reported there).  As @ShaileshB asks, I don't know what you mean when you say "want to clone", as it seems you already have a local repository, so `git clone` would not be an appropriate thing to do in that directory.  What is it that you expect to see that you're not seeing?

Comment: Try moving to the parent directory (`octacode.github.io` instead of `site`).

Answer (score 0):

That means you have:

- `git init` (initialize) a new local repository in `C:\user\asfat\octacode.github.io`
- created files and folders (like site)

Nothing has been added yet to the local Git repository, nothing has been committed.

Go back one level up, `git add .` and `git commit -m "My first commit"`.
If you try to add in the `site` folder, and if that folder is *empty*, you would not be able to add "nothing".

Check that you have defined a `remote origin` URL

```
git remote -v
# if not
git remote add origin https://github.com/asfat/asfat.github.io
git push -u origin main
```

Note that you would not be able to push back to octacode.github.io, unless you actually are [Kumar Shashwat (octacode)](https://github.com/octacode), and not [Asfat Uddin Rahat](https://github.com/asfat) .